# Conditional layout and action caching without a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pjax

I have an action on a controller where I'm using action caching. However I'm using the `layout: false` flag on that caching call since my layout has user dependent information like login status. This works perfectly.

Then I was adding the pjax-rails gem, which basically adds this code to the controller:

```
layout ->(c) { pjax_request? ? false : 'application' }
```

That is on some requests the layout isn't rendered. Now I (kinda logically) want to combine these two approaches together.

However when `pjax_request? == true` I get this error:

> There was no default layout for MyController

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

---

PS: This is easiest reproducible in this case:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  caches_action :index, :layout => false

  def index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost think this might be a bug in Rails. Check out this block of code around line 143 of `actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/actions.rb`:

```
body = controller.read_fragment(cache_path.path, @store_options)

unless body
  controller.action_has_layout = false unless @cache_layout
  yield
  controller.action_has_layout = true
  body = controller._save_fragment(cache_path.path, @store_options)
end

body = controller.render_to_string(:text => body, :layout => true) unless @cache_layout

controller.response_body = body
```

It looks like it's correctly rendering the body **without** a layout in the first `unless` block, but then it's forcing the template to render **with** a layout as part of the response body. And if you look at the stack trace, that's the line that leads to the exception.

I manually edited the file to `:layout => @cache_layout` (which always evaluates to `:layout => false` since it's guarded by an `unless`) and the view rendered as expected.

I'm not sure what you could do about this other than temporarily patch that file yourself and open a bug report. I might also be wrong about the behavior of that line, but it certainly looks like the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I hacked around there for a bit, and wrote a pull request that should fix the problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5328.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this in the future, as of rails 3, setting a default layout to the controller:

```
layout "application"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout

Seem to overcome this issue, that is indeed a rails defect.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to also provide a solution, if you do this it will solve your problem:

```
layout Proc.new {|controller|
  controller.action_has_layout = false
  false
}
```

Just forces the `action_has_layout` from @Brandan's answer